# running pdflatex through sublime text 2 does not work when I use \includegraphics

Tags: latex, sublimetext2, pdflatex

i'm running this sublime-text build script to create my pdf files with pdflatex

```
{
"cmd" : ["pdflatex", "${file_base_name}"],
"working_dir" : "$file_path",
"shell" : false }
```

The build-script works fine for creating pdfs with just text, but when I try to compile a simple .tex file using the graphicx package and try to insert a png with \includegraphics I get an errormessage:

> pdflatex: relocation error: pdflatex: symbol png_set_option, version PNG16_0 not defined in file libpng16.so.16 with link time reference
>   [Finished in 1.0s with exit code 127]

But when I create the pdf in the shell just using - `pdflatex filename` it works without any problems.

I really have no clue why that is. When I use the LateXTools plugin \includegraphics is also not working, that's why I created my own build script, and sadly, it's still not working...

Does anyone know why that could be, or how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This occurs as sublime provides it's own version of libpng.16.so.16

The solution I used is from the [arch forums.](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1605012#p1605012) - You replace Sublime's libpng.so with a link to your operating systems version:

```
cd /opt/sublime-text
sudo cp -R lib lib.bak
cd lib
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/libpng.so libpng16.so.16.2.0
```